# Android Project Lifecycle - before Activity Lifecycle ( Activity.onCreate() )

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

I'm looking to implement a SQLite database in an Android project that I'm currently working on. To my surprise, it appears the only way to create this, is in the Activity code itself. (My last experience with Java and local databases was with Derby, which was a local file I had not created within the code.)

My question is, **is there anything I can tap into that happens before the first Activity's onCreate()?** I'll relate this back to Windows Form applications, where you can access Main() before launching the Form (Activity equivalent).

If I have to create the database within the program's code, I want to check to see if it already exists, only once, before the Activities start.

Comment: You could have a separate Launcher activity that does the checks then launches your main activity.

Comment: You can use the Application's [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) method

Comment: @Androiderson I believe this is what I'm looking for. If you'd like to answer this with that, I'd make it the accepted answer.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting done. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Application's [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) method to run any code at the application start up (i.e. before any Activity).

Answer (score 1):

There is, but you don't need to.  SQLite databases (which are built into Android) are just files on the local filesystem.  Now you generally access them through either an ORM layer or through SQliteOpenHelper, which are Java interfaces to the database.  When you open it, you just tell it where the file is.  Generally you have a Singleton of the open helper or ORM layer class, so no per-Activity setup-  you just throw any of that you need in the constructor there, and let the Singleton take care of it in whatever Activity ends up creating it.

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended way of using a database](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) is to use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which automatically creates it the first time you try to access it. (And also handles updates.)